# How does ZeroMQ manage socket in zmq::proxy and zmq::poll?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I had a problem concerning ZeroMQ because I used pointer on a ZMQ socket for zmq::proxy and zmq::poll. Doing that occurs an exception with error 88 (Socket operation on non-socket).

Actually ZeroMQ wants the user to send a structure cast in void* ([source of the information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429907/zmq-poll-not-working))

I did some research in the official documentation but I didn't found why ZeroMQ doesn't use a pointer on the socket.

edit: This is the code I thought would be correct

```
zmq::socket_t frontend_;
zmq::socket_t backend_;
zmq::proxy(&frontend_, &backend_, nullptr);
```

and the code that is actually working is this one :

```
zmq::socket_t frontend_;
zmq::socket_t backend_;
zmq::proxy((void *)frontend_, (void *)backend_, nullptr);
```

It's strange for me. Why does ZeroMQ do it ?

Comment: Please post skeletal code to understand what you have attempted

Comment: CKmum I added the code to make my question more clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing strange in it.

A pointer is present in the `socket_t` class and an operator `static_cast<void *>()` method is returning this pointer instead of using the actual instance of the class.

[Can a cast operator be explicit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239356/can-a-cast-operator-be-explicit)

This post helped me to understand that a problem appears in the [official documentation test of `zmq`](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:asyncsrv). In c++11 it's impossible to use directly

```
zmq::proxy(frontend_, backend_, nullptr);
```

because the conversion is explicit in the `zmq` code. So you need to properly cast the socket like that :

```
zmq::proxy(static_cast<void *>(frontend_), static_cast<void *>(backend_), nullptr);
```